# Android activity and fragment lifecycle

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

This [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/visualization-android-activity) provide a visualization of the lifecycle for activity and fragment.
But it didn't really mention the full lifecycle when fragment is being triggered from an activity.
Can someone please explain what is the sequence of method will be triggered (both fragment and activity) when users change the device orientation?
Will this be the sequence:

1. Fragment.onPause,
2. Fragment.onSaveInstance,
3. Fragment.onStop,
4. Fragment.onDestroy,
5. Activity.onPause,
6. Activity.onSaveInstance,
7. Activity.onStop,
8. Activity.onDestory,
9. Activity create again ... and running
10. Fragment create again ... and running

Answer (score 3):

Just created an example and tested for you. I had a PlaceholderFragment attached in MainActivity onCreate.

The call stacks when user change Orientation:

```
07-09 15:47:59.932: I/System.out(9756): Fragment onPause
07-09 15:47:59.952: I/System.out(9756): Activity onPause
07-09 15:47:59.952: I/System.out(9756): Activity onSaveInstanceState
07-09 15:47:59.952: I/System.out(9756): Fragment onStop
07-09 15:47:59.952: I/System.out(9756): Activity onStop
07-09 15:47:59.952: I/System.out(9756): Fragment onDestroyView
07-09 15:47:59.952: I/System.out(9756): Fragment onDestroy
07-09 15:47:59.952: I/System.out(9756): Fragment onDetach
07-09 15:47:59.972: I/System.out(9756): Activity onDestroy
07-09 15:48:00.072: I/System.out(9756): Fragment onAttach
07-09 15:48:00.072: I/System.out(9756): Fragment onCreate
07-09 15:48:00.172: I/System.out(9756): Activity onCreate
07-09 15:48:00.172: I/System.out(9756): Fragment onCreateView
07-09 15:48:00.172: I/System.out(9756): Fragment onActivityCreated
07-09 15:48:00.172: I/System.out(9756): Fragment onStart
07-09 15:48:00.172: I/System.out(9756): Activity onStart
07-09 15:48:00.182: I/System.out(9756): Activity onResume
07-09 15:48:00.182: I/System.out(9756): Fragment onResume
```

I have also attached code below in case you want to experiment with it. (Edit: please see previous edit for code)

Also Android Developer guide has good explanation on [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Comment: I have done this before, but the sequences doesn't really make sense to me. For example, fragment is created first then only activity. Do you mind explain more on these?

Comment: @user970307, here is my interpretation, `Activity onCreate()` is called when activity **IS created**, meaning the application send a message to this function after components in activity are being created. What I mean component? `getSupportFragmentManager()` gives a `FragmentManager` as a component of `MainActivity` (FragmentActivity), and `PlaceholderFragment` is manipulated by `FragmentManager`. So entire `PlaceholderFragment` lifecycle lives within context of `MainActivity`. As mentioned above, it is reasonable the fragment (as a component) `onCreated` gets called prior to MainActivity's.

Comment: Also note that `PlaceholderFragment` class instance resides in Fragments of FragmentManager even after `onDestroy`. `onCreate` marks the *creation* of the fragment, it should be differentiated from construction or initialization.